# Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vercel

Tengo un proyecto desarrollado con Frontity y alojado en Vercel. Este proyecto ya está funcionando y lo he actualizado varias veces, la última fue en octubre. Hace una semana hice algunos cambios y al intentar actualizarlo me apareció el siguiente error en vercel:

```
[14:38:05.125] Retrieving list of deployment files...
[14:38:05.505] Downloading 43 deployment files...
[14:38:06.777] Skipping build cache since Node.js version changed from "16.x" to "18.x"
[14:38:06.823] Running "vercel build"
[14:38:07.342] Vercel CLI 28.8.0
[14:38:07.355] WARN! Did you mean to deploy the subdirectory "build"? Use `vc --cwd build` instead.
[14:38:07.472] WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings
[14:38:07.483] > Installing Builder: @frontity/now
[14:38:09.967] Downloading user files...
[14:38:09.978] Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=10.0.0" } in your `package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is released. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
[14:38:09.983] Installing dependencies...
[14:38:09.984] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[14:38:14.842] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[14:38:15.370] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[14:38:15.446] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[14:38:15.480] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[14:38:15.546] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[14:38:15.706] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[14:38:19.467] npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
[14:38:23.979] 
[14:38:23.979] added 1087 packages in 14s
[14:38:23.979] 
[14:38:23.979] 77 packages are looking for funding
[14:38:23.979]   run `npm fund` for details
[14:38:24.003] Running "build" script in "package.json"
[14:38:24.008] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7+...
[14:38:24.008] Running "npm run build"
[14:38:24.320] 
[14:38:24.320] > super-ingles-v1@1.0.0 build
[14:38:24.320] > frontity build
[14:38:24.320] 
[14:38:25.798] 
[14:38:25.799]   - mode: production
[14:38:25.799]   - target: both
[14:38:25.799]   - public-path: /static/
[14:38:25.799] 
[14:38:25.836] Building es5 bundle
[14:38:26.903] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[14:38:26.903]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[14:38:26.903]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[14:38:26.903]     at module.exports (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
[14:38:26.903]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
[14:38:26.903]     at handleParseError (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
[14:38:26.903]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
[14:38:26.904]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
[14:38:26.904]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
[14:38:26.904]     at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
[14:38:26.904]     at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
[14:38:26.906]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
[14:38:26.906]     at context.callback (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
[14:38:26.906]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:71
[14:38:26.932] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

La parte que marca como error es la siguiente:

```
[14:38:26.903] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[14:38:26.903]     at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
[14:38:26.903]     at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
[14:38:26.903]     at module.exports (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
[14:38:26.903]     at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
[14:38:26.903]     at handleParseError (/vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
[14:38:26.903]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
[14:38:26.904]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
[14:38:26.904]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
[14:38:26.904]     at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
[14:38:26.904]     at iterateNormalLoaders (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
[14:38:26.906]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:236:3
[14:38:26.906]     at context.callback (/vercel/path1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
[14:38:26.906]     at /vercel/path1/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:44:71
[14:38:26.932] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

En otras palabras, surgen los siguientes errores:

```
[14:38:26.903] Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
[14:38:26.932] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Nota: Ya intenté soluciones comunes reinstalar Node, actualizarlo, agregar "--openssl-legacy-provider".

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Answer (score 1):

Hola Daniel y a todos los que hayan tenido este problema.
En base a la info que encontré en [el foro de Frontity](https://community.frontity.org/t/a-new-error-command-npm-run-build-exited-with-1/6499/2) lo que hice fue modificar en el archivo **package.json** la versión de la engine de node a "16.3.0". En mi caso esa sección quedó así:

```
"engines": {
"node": "16.13.0",
"npm": ">=6.0.0" 
},
```

Recomiendo borrar la carpeta build y node_modules y luego correr los comandos:

```
npm install
npx frontity build
```

Luego de chequear que funciona en mi entorno local hice el push al repositorio y logré que el build en Vercel se ejecute correctamente.